# How to search non-html files with Qt's QHelpSearchEngine

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

My application is using several Qt help files (`qch`) which are produced by different teams. Let's say there's `good.qch` which was constructed from HTML files with extension `.html`, and `bad.qch` constructed from HTML files with extension `.xml`.

The application is using `QHelpEngine`, `QHelpSearchEngine` and related classes to display and search the help. The problem is that the search never finds any hits in `bad.qch`; it seems only `good.qch` is searched.

I've tried renaming the `.xml` files to `.html`, without modifying their content in any way. On this modified `bad.qch`, the search works perfectly.

Is there a way to make the Qt help framework search files other than `*.html`, or do I have to convince "team bad" to rename the files when creating the `qch`?

Comment: Not that I expect it, but would the downvoter explain themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read through the source code of `QHelpSearchEngine` and related classes (Qt 4.8.4) and it turns out there's a hardcoded list of extensions to search: `.html`, `.htm` and `.txt`. So there's no mechanism to search other files, at least in Qt 4.8.4.